# Is it possible to inherit from boost::histogram and set axes at runtime?

Tags: boost, boost-histogram

I am trying to replace a proprietary histogram implementation with `boost::histogram` but I am stuck. Is it possible to inherit from `boost::histogram` and set axes at runtime?

Comment: Does the [second example using `make_histogram`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/histogram/doc/html/histogram/guide.html#histogram.guide.making_histograms) answer your question? If not, can you supply a minimal example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: My need is to inherit and use boost::histogram as base class. I am using it internally with no problems but I can't figure out if I can use it as base class. The more I read about it I tend to believe I cannot.

Comment: In general you should not, unless types have been explicitly designed for inheritance (which is rare in C++ libraries, outside some very OOP libraries like Crypto++ that employ virtual functions for polymorphism, rather than virtual interfaces). Am I correct in thinking that the "and set axes at runtime" wasn't relevant to the question, actually?